# Значение слова «здравствуй»

Tags: семантика, значение

Уважаемые знатоки и любители русского языка. Кто сможет пояснить значение слова "здравствуй"?

Comment: Вы не знаете, что этим словом люди здороваются?!

Comment: Вы знаете об ином значении этого слова?

Answer (score 1):

[Происхождение слова "здравствуй" в этимологическом онлайн-словаре Крылова Г. А.](https://lexicography.online/etymology/%D0%B7/%D0%B7%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%B9)

> Образовано от 1-го лица единственного числа глагола *здравствовать*,
>   имевшего значение «приветствовать, желать здоровья». Слово
>   *здравствуй*, сказанное при встрече, имело, таким образом, значение «приветствую, желаю здравия».

[Происхождение слова "здравствуй" в этимологическом онлайн-словаре Успенского Л. В.](https://lexicography.online/etymology/%D0%B7/%D0%B7%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%B9)

> Вероятно, девять человек из десяти считают, что это повелительное
>   наклонение от «здравствовать». На деле же приветствие это родилось из
>   выражения «я здравствую тебя», т. е. «желаю тебе здоровья» (ср.
>   «здравица», «заздравный»).

[Происхождение слова "здравствуй" в этимологическом онлайн-словаре Шанского Н. М.](https://lexicography.online/etymology/%D0%B7/%D0%B7%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%B9)

> Искон. Объясняется по-разному. Или из здравствую (1-е л. ед. ч. от
>   здравствовать «приветствовать, желать быть здоровым») > *здравствуй* в
>   результате отпадения конечного безударного у, ср. *нет* < *нету*. Или как
>   форма повелит. наклонения *здравствуй* «будь здоров».